# Gradle: how to call task type twice from the custom task?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task

guys, help me, please.
I defined a task type into my `build.gradle`:

```
class BumpFrontendVersionTask extends DefaultTask {
    @Internal String jsonFilePath

    @TaskAction
    void bumpFrontendVersion() {
        def packageJsonPath = new File(jsonFilePath as String)
        def parsedPackageJson = new JsonSlurper().parse(packageJsonPath)
        parsedPackageJson.version = Optional.ofNullable(System.getenv('RELEASE_VERSION')).orElseGet { '0.0.0' }
        def packageJson = new JsonBuilder(parsedPackageJson).toPrettyString()
        def fileWriter = new FileWriter(packageJsonPath)
        fileWriter.write(packageJson)
        fileWriter.close()
    }
}
```

Also I made a custom task:

```
tasks.register('bumpFrontendVersion', BumpFrontendVersionTask) {
    description 'Task bumps frontend version with environment variable value'
    jsonFilePath 'frontend/package.json'
    jsonFilePath 'frontend/package-lock.json'
}
```

When I call this task `bumpFrontendVersion` it processes only 1 file (last one).

What shall I change in my code to launch my task type twice from one custom task?